# Attach included class to namespace?

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby class `Bar` in a file `models/bar.rb`:

```
class Bar
end
```

And a Ruby module `Foo` in my main program file:

```
module Foo
end
```

I would like to require/load/autoload `Bar` such that it's namespaced under `Foo`, i.e.:

```
module Foo
  autoload :Bar, 'models/bar.rb'
end

fb = Foo::Bar.new # yay!
```

However, the entities found by require/load/autoload are attached to the global namespace. In order for this to work, I have to edit `models/bar.rb` and wrap the class in `module Foo`..`end`. Is there a way to do this without having to do that?

Comment: Not sure how I missed that over an hour of frantic googling. Thanks @brito!

Comment: Note that banister's accepted answer to brito's link only makes modules accessible from other modules, and they are not actually included in the namespace. It is similar to the situation where a hash with a default value can provide values for a non-existing key without having that key-value stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. That is impossible under normal file loading. (If you read the file `models/bar.rb` not as Ruby code but as a string, and then `instance_eval` the string within `Foo`, then it is possible.)